# Funky mDNSResponder plist

Tags: macos, dns, bonjour

Well, I've never seen this one before - or have any idea how this would happen if you need to be in recovery to modify the file.

This was the current output of my com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist when I was digging to disable Bonjour Multicast Advertisments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.apache.httpd</string>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>XPC_SERVICES_UNAVAILABLE</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY</key>
        <string>YES</string>
    </dict>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/sbin/httpd-wrapper</string>
        <string>-D</string>
        <string>FOREGROUND</string>
    </array>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

What would these settings accomplish? Because these are different than default, to me it looks like its trying to divert the DNS queries somewhere else.

This could also be a result of hardening, but again, not sure how that would be possible if you need either SIP disabled, or need to be in recovery to accomplish.

Comment: That looks like the contents of /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist. Exactly where are you seeing this, how are you viewing it, and what version of macOS are you running?

Comment: MacMini 2018 (with T2) FileVault (Off) - macOS 10.14.6 (18G9216)

Yeah seemed strange to me too - not sure how it was altered with SIP enabled but thats a pretty alarming change considering the damage it could create.

Thank you for your input.